# Can TYPO3 backend run OWASP WAF conform

Tags: typo3, owasp

the TYPO3 backend triggers a lot of errors when installed on Azure with a tight OWASP ruleset enabled. Basically it is unusable for editors, since saving almost anything in the backend doesn't work.

Among the triggered rules are...
"ruleId":"942370", Detects clasic SQL injection probings 2/2
"ruleId":"942430", Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection (args):# of special characters exceeded (12)

The problem is, that TYPO3 is not the only application which runs on the same machine and we're not in control of the Web Application Firewall.

Is there a way for TYPO3 to run OWASP conform or would it be better to separate the applications and adjust the rules for TYPO3 accordingly?

Any recommendations would be very appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The most important information missing is the used TYPO3 version.

The code quality improves a lot from version to version but being compatible with the OWASP ruleset is IMHO currently not on the list but would be certainly very nice. What would be needed is some specific information which rules are not met

Comment: Hi Georg,

thank you for your reply and you basically answered my question already.
I wasn't looking so much for a specific solution, but more of an exchange of experiences. Perhaps other people encountered the same problems and would have some suggestions.

The TYPO3 version in use is 9.5. I could require the list of disabled rules though, if this would be of interest.

Comment: we are certainly intersted in the rules but speaking of OWASP also means that you shouldn't break https://owasp.org/Top10/A06_2021-Vulnerable_and_Outdated_Components/ which you do by using TYPO3 9.5 ;) maybe slack is the better place to discuss this. happy to support you with this topic if interested